# Semicircle/Rectangle collision detection

Tags: geometry, collision-detection

I have:

- A semicircle defined by a point (M), an angle (Θ) and a radius (r)
- A rectangle defined by four points (A, B, C, D)

The semicircle can be entirely inside the rectangle and vice versa.
 
Is there a way/algorithm (preferably in javascript) to detect collision between these 2 shapes ?

[image]

Comment: Is rectangle always axis-aligned?

Comment: not necessarily